# Bootstrap 4 left align breadcrumbs with right align text

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I´m trying to get something like this:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvDiJ.png)

It works with this:

```
<nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
<ol class="breadcrumb">
<li class="breadcrumb-item">Home </li>
<li class="breadcrumb-item">Level 1</li>
<li class="breadcrumb-item active">Level 2</li>
<li class="ml-auto">Some right align text</li>
</ol>
</nav>
```

In my case the html-code is generated by an php script.
The php script generates the "Some right align text"-part first from a postgre-database and subsequently the breadcrumb items fromthe same database. 
This means the generated html-code is

```
<nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
<ol class="breadcrumb">
<li class="ml-auto">Some right align text</li>
<li class="breadcrumb-item">Home </li>
<li class="breadcrumb-item">Library</li>
<li class="breadcrumb-item active">Data</li>
</ol>
</nav>
```

and this isn´t working for me, because everything is now right align.

Any suggestions how to fix this?
thank you in advance for your help

Comment: `Some right align text` should be the last item in the ordered list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily achive this the help of `FLEX` and its `ORDER` property

```css
.breadcrumb {display: flex;}
.breadcrumb li {margin-right: 20px;}
.breadcrumb li:first-child {order: 1; margin-left: auto;}
```

```html
<nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
<ol class="breadcrumb">
<li class="ml-auto">Some right align text</li>
<li class="breadcrumb-item">Home </li>
<li class="breadcrumb-item">Library</li>
<li class="breadcrumb-item active">Data</li>
</ol>
</nav>
```

Comment: Yeah! Thank you!

Comment: if this helped you then don;t forget to mark it right answer